# Bootstrap full width dropdown (Not Menu/Nav)

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, megamenu

I need to display a custom dropdown with very many options. All the **options are Dynamic and the rows of data are also dynamic** - Added using jquery.

I want therefore to have the dropdown occupy full width of the browser (Responsive) so that the many options are better viewable on the browser

Currently, the dropdown takes full width of the column (col-md-6) but **I want it to overlay on top of the other columns full width of the browser but still be relative to the city button clicked**

I have tried using bootstrap megamenu but even it does not span full width unless declared on the nav.

```
<style>
    .dropdown{
        position:relative;
    }
    .dropdown_content{
        z-index: 1000;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        right:0;
        left: 0;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <!-- City -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lender_city_id">City</label>
        <div class="dropdown btn btn-light text-dark w-100 d-flex justify-content-between">City <span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span></div>
    </div>
    {{--Cities Mega menu dropdown--}}
    <div class="dropdown_content mb-3 bg-dark text-light">
</div>
```

Image below shows what I have and what I need to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Remove `position: relative` from the dropdown add it to main row. please check if there is any `position: relative` property in column or form-control.

Comment: This did not work. I ended up having one static div whose contents  dynamically change based on the city dropdown clicked

Comment: Can you please share **jsfiddle** link so that it can be very easy to solve